# how to copy data along with the header in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to copy both the header and its data but my code is only copying the header and not the column that is along with it.

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as csvfile:

   reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',', quotechar='"')

   for row in reader:
        has_val=False

        for cell in row:

            if "VyOS" in cell:

                with open('esxtopresult_vyos.csv', 'ab') as ofile2:

                    ofile2.write('"'+cell+'",')
```

I am trying to copy a specific string out of a file and place it in another file along with its data.

Comment: I did, do you need more clarification?

Comment: welcome, sorry I just started using this site so I still make mistakes.

Comment: I'd recommend using pandas as it will be more straight forward and less messy

Comment: I assume from the code you are using Python 2?  Also I suggest you  explain what you are trying to do (give a sample CSV and the output you want to get). It looks like there might be an easier way.